# Donut chart python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

So I using this code to create a donut chart with python (inspired in this Donut plot [recipe](http://wwwu.edu.uni-klu.ac.at/mdragasc/codewiki/doku.php?id=pylabrecipes)):

```
def make_pie(sizes, text,colors,labels):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    col = [[i/255. for i in c] for c in colors]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.axis('equal')
    width = 0.35
    kwargs = dict(colors=col, startangle=180)
    outside, _ = ax.pie(sizes, radius=1, pctdistance=1-width/2,labels=labels,**kwargs)
    plt.setp( outside, width=width, edgecolor='white')

    kwargs = dict(size=20, fontweight='bold', va='center')
    ax.text(0, 0, text, ha='center', **kwargs)
    plt.show()

c1 = (226,33,7)
c2 = (60,121,189)

make_pie([257,90], "Gender (AR)",[c1,c2],['M','F'])
```

which results in:

[image]

My problem is that now I want the respective percentages. For that I was simply adding the argument:

```
autopct='%1.1f%%'
```

like this:

```
kwargs = dict(colors=col, startangle=180,autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

but this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draw.py", line 30, in <module>
    make_pie([257,90], "Gender (AR)",[c1,c2],['M','F'])
  File "draw.py", line 13, in make_pie
    outside, _ = ax.pie(sizes, radius=1, pctdistance=1-width/2,labels=labels,**kwargs)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docstring:

> ```
> If *autopct* is not *None*, return the tuple (*patches*,
>   *texts*, *autotexts*), where *patches* and *texts* are as
>   above, and *autotexts* is a list of
>   :class:`~matplotlib.text.Text` instances for the numeric
>   labels.
> ```

So if you want to unpack the result of `pie()` using `autopct` you need 3 values:

```
kwargs = dict(colors=col, startangle=180, autopct='%1.1f%%')
outside, _, _ = ax.pie(sizes, radius=1, pctdistance=1-width/2,
                       labels=labels,**kwargs)
```

Or maybe it will be more robust without unpacking so it works with or without `autopct`:

```
outside = ax.pie(sizes, radius=1, pctdistance=1-width/2,
                 labels=labels,**kwargs)[0]
```