# Piechart with Matplotlib/Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I need to draw a plot as much similar as possible to this:

[image]

The problem is that I don't have any difficulties to draw "classic" pie charts, but I can't find any reference on how to:

- Make them empty at the center;
- Make a little white space between slices;

Any idea?

Thanks in advance, Gianluca

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://medium.com/@krishnakummar/donut-chart-with-python-matplotlib-d411033c960b

Comment: Show your efforts. Try to search your topic on search engine if you haven't developed anything yet !

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154062/2454357).