# Customizing Nested Donut Charts - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I believe I am 90% of the way to solving this issue. As can be seen on the attached image, I am trying to create a nested donut chart based on two groups (rem and deep), the values have been plotted to show the proportion (in relation to 100%) a user is achieving. I want to display this in the "apple health ring style", in order for this to be effective, I want to highlight the two "types" (rem and deep) using two different colors. Within the image you can see the DF, the code applied to generate the existing view and the output. To summarize, I want to;

1. Assign a set color to "rem", and a different one for "deep"
2. Remove the axis labels and tick marks
3. Ideally (although I can probably do this), better format the labels (in some way).
4. Output to image file with black background

```py
import re
# create donut plots
my_dpi=150
plt.figure(figsize=(1500/my_dpi, 900/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
startingRadius = 0.7 + (0.3* (len(Ian_MitchellRD)-1))

for index, row in Ian_MitchellRD.iterrows():
    scenario = row["index"]
    percentage = row["Ian Mitchell"]
    textLabel = scenario + ': ' + percentage+ '%'
    print(startingRadius)
    percentage = int(re.search(r'\d+', percentage).group())
    remainingPie = 100 - percentage

    donut_sizes = [remainingPie, percentage]
    #colors = ['#FDFEFE','#AED6F1','#5cdb6f','#AED6F1']
    plt.title('Proportion of Recommended Sleep Type being Achieved')
    plt.text(0.05, startingRadius - 0.20, textLabel, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', color='black')
    plt.pie(donut_sizes, radius=startingRadius, startangle=90, colors=colors, frame=True,
            wedgeprops={"edgecolor": "white", 'linewidth': 2}, )
    startingRadius-=0.3

# equal ensures pie chart is drawn as a circle (equal aspect ratio)
plt.axis('equal')

# create circle and place onto pie chart
circle = plt.Circle(xy=(0, 0), radius=0.35, facecolor='white')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

See image of what the code current generates:

UPDATE:

I amended the code per the recommendation to look into the example suggested, code is now;

```py
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
width = 0.25
fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)

data_1 = Ian_MitchellRD.iloc[0]['Ian Mitchell']
data_2 = Ian_MitchellRD.iloc[1]['Ian Mitchell']

remainingPie_1 = 100 - data_1
remainingPie_2 = 100 - data_2

donut_sizes_1 = [remainingPie_1, data_1]
donut_sizes_2 = [remainingPie_2, data_2]

pie, _ = ax.pie(donut_sizes_1, radius=1, colors=['black','lightgreen'],startangle=90)
plt.setp( pie, width=width, edgecolor='black')

pie2, _ = ax.pie(donut_sizes_2, radius=1-width,startangle=90, colors=['black','pink'])
plt.setp( pie2, width=width, edgecolor='black')
plt.title("Ian Mitchell - Average % of REM + Deep Sleep vs Recommended", fontfamily='Consolas', size=16, color='white')

#setting up the legend

greenbar= mlines.Line2D([], [], color='lightgreen', marker='s', linestyle='None',
                          markersize=10, label='REM Sleep')
pinkbar = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='pink', marker='s', linestyle='None',
                          markersize=10, label='Deep Sleep')

plt.legend(handles=[greenbar, pinkbar],prop={'size': 12}, loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

generating the following;

I would really appreciate guidance on adding labels either, directly on the relevant sections of the chart - i.e. the green chart has a label of around 94%, and the pink segment around 55%.

Thanks,

[New Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9CS5.png)

Comment: The way to do all these things can be found by searching for them individually here on SO. That's why it's requested that you only include one question per post, so that a suitable duplicate can be found if it exists. As it stands, I don't know which duplicate to assign to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double donut chart in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153457/double-donut-chart-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Hi @DizietAsahi I do not believe its a duplicate as that thread gives a different solution to a different problem, yes its related to the same visual, but its a different use case and result being desired. I believe using nested donuts in the "apple health rings" style is a different visualization technique which other users would benefit from seeing a solution for. Do you have any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: I don't see the difference personally, and 2 of your questions are addressed in the duplicate: - setting different colors (which simply entails passing different values to `colors=`) and - removing the axes spines (`ax.set_axis_off()`)

Comment: @DizietAsahi I have updated per your earlier advice, but I am still somewhat stuck with the labeling element of what I'm trying to do. I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look if you have the chance? Many thanks,