# How to plot ring by zones under two variables using matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
Date    A ZONE_GEN  A ZONE_LOAD  B ZONE_GEN  A ZONE_LOAD
1-1-2010     20             15          30            25
1-2-2010     30             25          40            35
....         ...            ...         ...           ...
1-12-2010    15             20          20            14
```

I want to create two new columns having names "Gen" and "LOAD" then sum each column ending with "Gen" in GEN column likewise column ending with Load I would like to get output as below:

```
Date    A ZONE_GEN  A ZONE_LOAD  B ZONE_GEN  B ZONE_LOAD
1-1-2010     20             15          30            25
1-2-2010     30             25          40            35
....         ...            ...         ...           ...
1-12-2010    15             20          20            14

   Gen   Load  A ZONE_GEN/Gen ... B ZONE_LOAD/LOAD    
   50     45      40%         ...      55.56%
   70     60      42.86%      ...      58.33%
   ...    ...     ...         ... 
   35     34      42.86%      ...      41.18%
```

Then ring plot-using matplotlib- the row having maximum "Gen" for percentage values and likewise for row having maximum "Load" for each zone and I hope the plot looks like the figure in the following link

[image: expected output]

Comment: Thanks, tdy , for your help

Comment: See [Double donut chart in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153457/double-donut-chart-in-matplotlib)